# How can I use a string variable in .bat for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

In a .bat file, it's ok to use a char-type variable in for-loop. The code below, for example,

```
@echo off
for /l %%p in (15,2,20) do (
    echo %%p
)
```

gives "15 17 19", as expected. But it doesn't work anymore if I use a string-type variable,

```
@echo off
for /l %%parameter in (15,2,20) do (
    echo %%parameter
)
```

I wonder if it's possible to make the 2nd piece of code work. Can somebody help me out? Many thanks.

Comment: No, this is not possible, you have to use a single character as a `for` meta-variable…

Comment: Not that you can, but what reason would you have for needing / wanting to?

Comment: You could have answered your own question just by reading the help file for the `FOR` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `%value%` is used to define variables that contain more than one character. The `%%` is used to define variables consisting of a single character.

Since only `%%` is allowed in the `for` loop, `%value%` cannot be used to define variables with more than one character. In this case, the only option is to define a single character variable using `%%`; such as `%%p`.

The syntax for the `for` loop is available below:

```
for %%a in (list) do command [ parameters ]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an ordinary environment variable defined with a for metavariable in place of the for metavariable:

```
@Echo off

 Set "Loop[1]=%%#"
 Set "Loop[2]=%%@"

 For /l %Loop[1]% in (1 1 5) Do For /l %Loop[2]% in (5 1 9) Do (
  <nul set /p=%Loop[1]% + %Loop[2]%=
  Cmd /c Set /A %Loop[1]% + %Loop[2]%
  Echo(
 )
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/F9HPj7q.jpg